# Parsing Source Code For Logger Lines in Java

Tags: java, parsing, logging, string-formatting, type-mismatch

I am trying to read the source codes of an application, and by parsing them, find the logger lines and determine those with type mismatch between the formatted string and inputs. An example:

```
    appLogger.debug(()->“There are %d %s 
           errors occurred in method %s”, 
           anInteger, anInteger,aString);
```

As an example, above the second formatter and the corresponding error has type mismatch. But when these occur at runtime, such as using methods etc. it cannot be detected during compilation.

I tried reflection, etc. but since I am new to programming, I could not find a way of doing this. Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Writing a new checkstyle check would be one way to do this: https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/writingchecks.html

Comment: This is not an easy task. Definitely not for programming beginners. There are too many possibilities what would have to be considered in such a test.
To summarize this here in a simple answer is too complicated.
A way to go is to use a tool specialized for such analyis like Checkstyle, Findbugs ore PMD

Comment: Note that any object, including an Integer, is compatible with %s in a Formatter string.

Comment: I thought that by using reflection, loading all the related classes, such as imports and itself, and while parsing lines, searching the inputs to formatters in methods of these classes, I thought I could handle it, but I couldn’t have achieved this yet. I will try the checkstyle tho. Thanks for all answers.